# General solution of trigonometric inequalities

Tags: inequality, trigonometry

We have

$$
\cos  x\ge -\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}\quad \Leftrightarrow \quad x\in \left[ 0+2n\pi ;\frac{3\pi}{4}+2n\pi \right] \cup \left[ \frac{5\pi}{4}+2n\pi ;2\pi +2n\pi \right] ,n\in \mathbf{Z}
\\
\cos  x\ge -\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}\quad \Leftrightarrow \quad x\in \left[ -\frac{3\pi}{4}+2n\pi ;\frac{3\pi}{4}+2n\pi \right] ,n\in \mathbf{Z}
$$

How to show (formal)

$
A=\left[ 0+2n\pi ;\frac{3\pi}{4}+2n\pi \right] \cup \left[ \frac{5\pi}{4}+2n\pi ;2\pi +2n\pi \right] ,n\in \mathbf{Z}
\\
B=\left[ -\frac{3\pi}{4}+2n\pi ;\frac{3\pi}{4}+2n\pi \right] ,n\in \mathbf{Z}
$

is same?

Comment: Can you please indicate what is what on the graph using MathJax and text?

Comment: Your posted question seems confusing to me.  Could you please review it to see if you have any typographical errors?  If so, please correct them.  For example, in the first part of your question, you have the two constraints $~\cos x \geq \dfrac{\sqrt{2}}{2},~$ and $~\cos x \geq - \dfrac{\sqrt{2}}{2}. ~$ Doesn't this first constraint make the second one redundant?  That is, if you have that $~\cos x \geq \dfrac{\sqrt{2}}{2},~$ doesn't that automatically imply that $~\cos x \geq - \dfrac{\sqrt{2}}{2} ~?$

Comment: Hint: For points in the set, the value of $n$ that shows them to be in $A$ and the value of $n$ that shows them to be in $B$ are not necessarily the same. Also consider: $[-\frac{3\pi}4;\frac{3\pi}4] = [-\frac{3\pi}4;0]\cup [0;\frac{3\pi}4]$.